# separate char[] from comma

Tags: arrays, c, split, char, strtok

I have a program that need's to communicate client/server with socket's.

I need to receive the data at real time and work with the data.

Atm I'm receiving the data all in a char array[] but the data is separated by comma. I'm trying to find a way to separate the data.

I've tried the `strtok`, separate by comma but stop the connection with server, so I got only 1 piece of data.

My code is this one:

```
#include<stdio.h> //printf
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>    //socket
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<unistd.h>
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc , char *argv[]) 
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char message[1000] , server_reply[2500];
    char* chars_array = strtok(server_reply, ",");
    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 51717 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

//keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {
       /* printf("Enter message : ");
        scanf("%s" , message);
        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;1
        }*/
        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2500 , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
            break;
        }
        puts("Server reply :");
        //puts(server_reply);
        //MessageBox(NULL, subchar_array, NULL, NULL);
        chars_array = strtok(NULL, ",");
        puts (chars_array);
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that the first call of strtok only returns the first token?

Comment: `strtok` also modifies the string you pass to it. If you want to get the second, third, etc. Token from the same source string, call strtok again with `strtok(NULL,',');`

Comment: Thanks, that helped ;D

Comment: basicly what happens is strtok "cuts off" part of the source string by moving it and setting the separators to 0, causing the string to be  "tokenized" as far as other programs know. Thats why it modifies the source string, too.

Answer (score 1):

The first call of `strtok` will only return the first token of the string you are seperating. To get the other tokens from the same source string, simply call `strok(NULL,',');` again until you are through with all of them. If there are no tokens left, this call will return `NULL` instead, so be careful.

Additional, take notice that strtok actually modifies the string that you pass to it. If you don't want that, make a copy for tokenizing first using `strcpy`.